Is it possible to add automated voice when making a call in Android?
"I am developing a crash detection application and I am wondering if it is possible to include an automated voice feature when a call is initiated. Essentially, in the event of a crash, the app would automatically call the user's preferred contacts, and an automated voice talks asking for help if the user is unable to speak."

yeah, it is possible in many ways on your requirements.
I have done a similar thing but in some other flow in which I go error text and by the native text-to-speech event I can produce an automated voice that tells about the error or what to do in case. There are so many libraries available on this that even catch your errors and you can deal with it in many ways.
Search for tts or crash analytics as well.  ###Good luck
